# How to make Jenkins project public

Tags: jenkins

I want to make my Jenkins job public. Therefore, I followed the tutorial from here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

My job is called `management` and is located in a folder called `management-all`.

I therefore went to "*Manage and Assign Roles*" and I created a new role with the pattern `manag.*`.

I've added it the following permissions:

```
Job-Build
Job-Read
Job-Workspace
```

There are several other roles with the same permissions. The jobs they cover are public.

However, my job doesn't appear to be public.

What else should I add?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have several jobs that I want to keep private, but want to expose either a view or a job to the public.